# Using 2 B channels in a BRI ISDN connection

Tags: telephony, isdn

I am trying to use 2 B channels in and ISDN BRI 2B+D connection. One for voice, and the other for device specific commands over HDLC. I am using the CAPI 2.0 API. I can configure one B channel as voice or HDLC but, I can't figure out how to configure the connection to use 2 B channels at the same time.

Comment: Sanity check: did you put the CAPI_REGISTER 2nd parameter dwMaxLogicalConnection to 2? Other then that you may need more detail in your question: is your second CONNECT_REQ failing somehow? Or are you expecting a CONNECT_IND that is not coming? Or do you have trouble understanding how the PLCI identifier works? Does "configure" mean setting BProtocol structure flags in the CAPI application or configuring the controller on the CAPI driver side? Sorry, but with little information it is hard to judge if this is a beginner or expert level problem.

Comment: Kris, Yes I register 2 B channels. The issue is the device we are simulating/eventually connecting to allocates 2 B channels in a single CONNECT_REQ/ISDN SETUP message. One for Voice and one for HDLC data. My question is, is it possible to negotiate 2 channels in a single CONNECT_REQISDN /SETUP message. I am not an ISDN expert and have tried googling this and I haven't found anything.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, not unless you have access to some manufacturer specific extensions. Personally I would link the lines logically together on application level: either through counting line numbers (PLCI) or using prefixes in CLIP and DNIS. Otherwise try these guys: https://www.xcapi.com/?lang=en. As far as I'm aware, they where the last members of the CAPI standard organization and still sell CAPI based products.